# Shell script to switch processes from one server to other server in case of failovers

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I am trying to develop something with shell scripting to get the below results:

1. Some cron jobs/monitoring scripts are scheduled one the primary database server.
2. Say if the primary server fails over to standby server.
3. I want the cron jobs/monitoring to automatically start running on standby server and stop on primary server in this case.

Can somebody help me with the logic to be used here please?

Comment: A bad RAM differs greatly from a full disk or from a sudden reboot or from an unexpected termination of a server process.  So please define "the primary server fails".

Comment: By primary server fail, I meant that if the server crashes due to any OS issues, and never comes back up automatically.It could either be a Bad RAM, or a sudden disk crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the secondary server:

use crontab to set the path of the command

- - - - - /bin/bash scriptname

> a bashscript can attempt to get a heartbeat from the server
>
> attempt a connection to the service

```
status=nmap <ipaddr> -PN -p ssh | egrep 'open|closed|filtered'

if [ $status = "close" ]
then
/path/to/command
fi
```